# Bootstrap multiple labels and input on same line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place two labels and two inputs on the same line. Is this even possible?

I want it to look like this all on the same line:

[Label][Input][Button] WhiteSpace  [Label2][Input2]

What I have so far

```
   <form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      <span class="input-group-btn ">
         <button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-click="click()">...</button>
       </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @IamRaviteja's answer is the right way to do it. Also check out the [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) for more examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Bootstrap form-inline & custom-control-inline classes.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="control-group custom-control-inline">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn ">
                            <button type="button" class="btn" data-ng-click="click()">...</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group custom-control-inline">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls form-check-inline">
                        <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" />
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: add description and say how to solve the problem in this answer

Comment: @janith1024 Okay

Answer (score 2):

This may help you

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Your label</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Your label</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
  </div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hLf32wda/4/)

Comment: So is there a way to do it without my labels looking like a button? Basically the label without the border. When the addon has the border it kind of gives the impression that the field is a textbox and editable when it is just a label

Comment: I want it to be a normal label saying "Name" then the input box for the name and a button next to the input box Labeled "search". On that same line I need another label saying "Phone" and next to that I need an input box for a phone number. So it would be [Name][InputBox][SearchButton] [Phone][InputBox]. I cant seem to get it all on one line for some reason and to fill the entire div

Answer (score 0):

Raviteja's solution is good but the following code will create the form as you mentioned in the comment (" without my labels looking like a button"). Bootstrap 3.3.7 is used.

```
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Email</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="margin-left:30px">
  <label class="form-label">Password</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group" style="margin-left:30px">
  <div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
  </div>
</div>
</form>"
```